# how do I read the output of an external program while it is running in python

Tags: python, console, subprocess, stdout, minecraft

I'm trying to make a bot that controls a minecraft server and I've managed to make start and send commands to the server, however I can't get the output of the server while it is running what I have now will only send me the output after the server is terminated kind of like a log.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(executable,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE, text=True)
out, err = process.communicate()
print(out)
print(err)
```

I would like to be able to use that server information to create a console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your project I think you mean to get the console/logs?
anyway if that is your doubt.

here is the answer

```py
while True:
    with open("XXXX\logs\latest.log","r") as f:
        console = f.read()
        await ctx.send(console)
```

Lemme know if this gives you an error or you have additional doubts!

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm not sure this is what I want, can you read the logs as the server is running? @Shashankh_

Comment: yes you can read the logs while the server is running

Comment: thanks a lot it worked perfectly, I think I am going to keep it as my method of getting the output because I can run it completely independently. It didn't fix my main issue however. The program still doesn't take inputs when it is not sending the log lines in the channel, I thought it was because of stdout but this proved me wrong, if you have any clues I'd greatly appreciate it @Shashankh_

Comment: it is not taking any inputs because of the while loop. i think you would have to use something else rather than while loop since the loop never breaks and it doesnt move to the next part of the code. hope you understand @PabloSAILLY